# How to query JSON data in python #noobie

Tags: python, json

Say I have JSON data like so:

```
{
    "friends": {
        "Charlie": {
            "gender": "female",
            "age": "28"
        },
        "Josh": {
            "gender": "male",
            "age": "22"
        },
        "Annie": {
            "gender": "female",
            "age": "24"
        }
    }
}
```

***What's the best/most pythonic way to "query" all my friend's age?***

I understand that I can drill into a specific dataset by calling:

```
var_holding_json['friends']['Josh']['age']
```

But I can't grasp how I can go from this to

1. "get **all** my friends' age".
2. "get all my friends' names whose age is > 22"

Thanks for any pointer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you pur the data in `data` you can use

```
[data['friends'][x]['age'] for x in data['friends']]
```

If you want to get only the names of your friends whose age > 22 you can do the following:

```
[x for x in data['friends'] if data['friends'][x]['age'] > 22]
```

Comment: This is the pythonic way :)

Comment: Yes, Sensei Miyagi - it is... :D

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution assuming the json above is stored in a variable named data.

```
for friend in data["friends"]:
    print(data["friends"][friend]["age"])

for friend in data["friends"]:
    age = int(data["friends"][friend]["age"])
    if (age > 22):
        print(friend)
```

Comment: (I've edited a second query into my question while you were already posting your answer. Thanks for your speedy response and pls excuse my "audible".)

Comment: Thank you so much, @Sri. Your incredibly quick and helpful response is most appreciated - especially since somone was equally quick to downvote my question. :( #sucksbeinganoob

Comment: No worries. Keep trying. Someone else posted a much cleaner solution using list comprehension you might want to check out.